# How can I run a piece of code ONLY if WP Admin is subpage A, subpage B, or subpage C?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I know similar questions have been answered - I've read some of those answers but, for the life of me, it seems there's something I'm missing/"not getting". So, here goes.

I'm trying to build an admin menu for a WP theme I'm creating from scratch. I've created some sub-pages, and now I want to do a check in enqueue.php so that a stylesheet.css loads ONLY if the user is on one of those pages, and NOT on the whole menu. As far as I understand, I should do a logic check if the page currently displayed is, say, page A, B, or C from MY menu, and have the stylesheet load ONLY if that's true.

Following a YouTube tutorial about theme building, I've reached a stage where my code's this:

```
function themename_load_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
  echo $hook;
    if ( ($hook != 'toplevel_page_A') || ($hook != 'toplevel_page_B') ) {
    return;
  }
  wp_register_style( 'themename_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/themename.admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style('themename_admin');
  wp_register_script( 'themename-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/themename.admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'themename-admin-script' );
}

add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", 'themename_load_admin_scripts' );
```

...aaaand it doesn't work. As an extra question, since I want to check multiple pages, not only two, would it be better if I did this check using an array? And if yes... how?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Did you check if the value of $hook is correct for the pages? As for the your second question you can use in_array function of php https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: Yup. I've actually copy-pasted the results into the code. No go :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yay, it works!

After @Pankaj told me how to pull this off with arrays, I looked into it, implemented a different take, and it STILL didn't work. After making sure it wasn't because of typos, wrong values, or anything of that kind, I remembered a very-very annoying quirk of Firefox Nightly: sometimes SOME things stop working if there's an impeding update, for reasons I can't really explain. And lo and behold, there was another impeding update. I downloaded it, restarted the browser, and auto-magically everything worked.

This includes BOTH the array-based solution AND my previous one, mind you. I honestly don't know WTF they're smoking at Mozilla, and how Firefox ends up borking this hard whenever there's an update knocking on the door.

Anyways, to clarify, BOTH the code above should work - it was the browser's fault - AND the new, array-based implementation, that follows for anyone interested:

```
<?php
/*

    =========================================
              Admin Enqueue Functions
    =========================================
*/

function themename_load_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
  echo $hook;

  $themenameAdminpages = array('toplevel_page_themename_settings', 'themename_page_themename_style_and_looks', 'themename_page_themename_functionality', 'themename_page_themename_social', 'themename_page_themename_seo', 'themename_page_themename_about' );
  if ( in_array($hook, $themenameAdminpages)) {
    wp_register_style( 'themename_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/themename.admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('themename_admin');
    wp_register_script( 'themename-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/themename.admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'themename-admin-script' );
  }
}

add_action( "admin_enqueue_scripts", 'themename_load_admin_scripts' );
```

PS: I know the names I'm using suck. As does my "code".